# Ember associated child records disappearing after reverting change to association

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

After changing an association and then changing it back (a couple of times), the association is lost.

```
    var newCar = MyApp.CarModel.find('hummer');
    MyApp.Person.find('wycats').set('car', newCar);
    var oldCar = MyApp.CarModel.find('toyota');
    MyApp.Person.find('wycats').set('car', oldCar);
```

Not very easy to explain, but very easy to see in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vz3E6/2/

Click the buttons in this order and you will see that the association is lost: 1, 2, 1, 2

I am using `ember-latest` and `ember-data-latest`.

*EDIT*: I have created a copy of this question as an issue on the ember-data issue tracker here: [#465](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/465)

Comment: Always happens on the 4th alternation

Comment: Yes, you must click both buttons twice in that order for this to happen

Comment: `MyApp.Person.find('wycats').get('car')` on the fourth alternation returns `null` - but `oldCar` does not: http://jsbin.com/ijicor/54/

Comment: even stranger - if you use `MyApp.Person.find('wycats').set('car', oldCar);` twice in a row, the issue is eliminated: http://jsbin.com/ijicor/54/edit

Comment: After looking into this I think this is actually an Ember bug. It's worth posting it to here - https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Saying that, Luke Melia (who edited your question) is one of the Emberjs authors so he may have an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest version of Ember Data. When Ember Data detects that a change to a child will effectively undo an earlier, as-yet-uncommitted change, it rolls back the parents, but fails to actually roll back the child and (because of some messy internal details) winds up setting it to null instead.

We have [an open pull request introducing hasOne associations](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/475) which happens to fix it with [this line](https://github.com/mhelabs/ember-data/commit/592d85ad2914cd5f24ef61188f1264a1ea87ded0#L5R283), as proven by [this test](https://github.com/mhelabs/ember-data/commit/592d85ad2914cd5f24ef61188f1264a1ea87ded0#L13R544).